# What to do with question when project is cancelled?

Tags: support

I have four questions trying to find the problem with a serial port (asked as I found more information from trying what was in the answers).

The problem is still persisting but we have decided to do the project in Java now to avoid the problem altogether.

No correct answer was given in any of the questions and I will never find a solution as the project was scrapped.

What should I do? They are dropping my accept rate, but as they do not give any helpful advice (my opinion as we never managed to solve the problem) I dont want to just accept high vote answers and give future searchers false hope.

What is the procedure for dealing with question in this situation?

Answer (score 12):

Do not accept answers which do not solve the problem.

And do not worry too much about your accept rate - 89% is a good rate. If someone decides to not answer if you have an 89% instead of 95%, this answerer is likely to give not that good advice (and certainly does not deserve any upvotes).

Answer (score 8):

If the answer is no longer relevant to **you**, it changes relatively little.

It is *still* a description of a concrete problem that others might have with answer tailored towards this specific problem.

You should just leave the questions as is, optionally noting that you are no longer looking for answers. This way *others* that search for similar answers will find the traces you (and the answerers) left behind and will know what kind of answers (or non-answers) you got.

**tl;dr**: do nothing, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to post an answer yourself and accept it. Write down your findings and details about what was helpful/unhelpful and correct/incorrect in the other answers that were given on your question.

Comment: This won't work in this case as the author has chosen to change something else such that the problem is no longer a problem.  It's silly to answer "Is mark and space parity \[in serial communications\] possible using `boost.asio` \[in C++\]?" with "If you use the Java Serial Port from serialio.com, you don't have to worry about Boost at all."

Comment: @Kevin I agree that in this particular case, my suggestion won't be of much use but I posted a general option.

Comment: You posted a general option for what to do when you don't get any good answers.  That wasn't the question. Instead, the OP asked "What to do with question when project is cancelled?" and no good answers had been given.