# What should I do about my question with no real correct answer available?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I asked a [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495490/is-there-a-way-around-sql-servers-deferred-name-resolution) that doesn't really have a valid answer. The comments and answer provided detail some possibilities and other issues surrounding the question, but don't give a specific answer. I expect the actual answer to my question is simply "No, there is no workaround", but without that answer and a specific reason why not, I am hesitant to mark an answer as there is currently no real solution to the issue. I realise I could start a bounty on the question, however, it seems as though given there is a Microsoft connect issue open on it, that it is unlikely to get a satisfactory answer.

Should I close the question? If so, I risk losing any comments etc that have arisen through peoples knowledge and research.

Should I simply leave it open and hope that at some point in the future, someone updates it if/when future versions of SQL Server make it a non issue and resolve it?

Comment: Yes, leave it open. There is nothing wrong with a question with no accepted answer. Make sure you provide as much info as possible, like a link to the issue, etc.

Comment: It's kind of what I was leaning towards. I seem to be getting a few unanswered questions at the moment. Some I will put up for a bounty if I think that'll help get an answer. I just want to make sure that my accept rate isn't due to the fact I am asking silly questions, or just not being able to articulate my problem well enough.

Comment: People can still comment on a closed question, so you wouldn't be losing that aspect.  It's only once a question is locked (or deleted of course) that people cannot comment.  For what it's worth, I agree with agf, though.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'd go with the consensus here (albeit through only 2 comments and no answers). It seems as though this question is pertinent to itself (i.e. No real answer available :))

Comment: You may go through some relevant discussion on this question: [What to do with question when project is cancelled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109617/what-to-do-with-question-when-project-is-cancelled/)

Comment: About the accept rate, I think you can stop caring about it. Accept whatever that you feels answer your question the best, and leave open questions without a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Related question: [Should I answer my own question with “it can't be done”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125855/167867)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downside of leaving a question unanswered is that it adds noise to the [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) filter. However, this downside is mitigated by time, as the question drops down in the list.

The upside is that leaving the question in tact with no answer provides useful information. The next person knows he is likely facing a dead end and needs to find a new path.

If there is a partial workaround, even if imperfect, and a better one seems unlikely, it is good to highlight it by marking it as the answer. Should a better solution be found later, that new answer can then become the accepted answer.